# Chi-Square with multiple samples

Tags: r, categorical-data, chi-squared-test, multivariate-analysis

I am not sure exactly how I should word this question, but is there a way to test the impact of a given factor on categorical distributions when I have multiple (independent) samples from the different levels of that factor?

To give a more concrete example: lets say I want to know if movie theaters in one town sell snacks to a different proportion of their customers than movie theaters in a different town. My data is:

| Town | Theater | Bought Snacks | Did Not Buy Snacks |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 10 | 30 |
| 1 | B | 75 | 100 |
| 2 | C | 50 | 62 |
| 2 | D | 84 | 95 |
| 2 | E | 12 | 5 |

In this case, I am interested in the impact of the factor "Town" on the number of customers who did and did not buy snacks. Each theater is an independent sample, and they should all be weighted equally.

I think if I were just comparing two theaters, I could use Chi-square, but is there a similar test I could use that takes the multiple theaters into account (while only comparing between the two town groups)? I think this test would need to account for the variation within the town groups and see if the variation between them exceeds that.

I also see that I could get the ratio of customers who bought snacks for each theater, and then compare these between towns using the t-test (or something similar), but I feel like that would be throwing away data since each customer is basically an independent test.

Any help or solutions in R would be particularly appreciated.

Comment: Try binomial logistic regression.